# Laravel DOMPDF exceed memory limit

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have an issue with Laravel DOMPDF package.
I've set the php.ini memory limit to 2G and launched a queue with --timeout=3600.
The script is a foreach with a helper function called every times, it produces pdfs for 7/8 minutes, than it stops doing it and after 10 minutes it returns in the terminal

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

 Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

 at vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Style.php:577
   573▕             //Early check on cache, before converting $length to array
   574▕             if (isset($cache[$key])) {
   575▕                 return $cache[$key];
   576▕             }
 ➜ 577▕             $length = [$length];
   578▕         } else {
   579▕             $key = implode("@", $length) . "/$ref_size";
   580▕             if (isset($cache[$key])) {
   581▕                 return $cache[$key];


  Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

 Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

 at vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Style.php:577
   573▕             //Early check on cache, before converting $length to array
   574▕             if (isset($cache[$key])) {
   575▕                 return $cache[$key];
   576▕             }
 ➜ 577▕             $length = [$length];
   578▕         } else {
   579▕             $key = implode("@", $length) . "/$ref_size";
   580▕             if (isset($cache[$key])) {
   581▕                 return $cache[$key];

     +1 vendor frames 
 2   [internal]:0
     Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

I'm using tables and I've read that it may be for that reason.
Thanks to anyone who could help me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
//helper
use App\Helpers\GeneratePdfHelper;

//models
use App\Models\Province;
use App\Models\Process;
use App\Models\Movement;
//others
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class GeneratePdfFiles implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $process_id;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($process_id)
    {
        $this->process_id = $process_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        
        $process = Process::find($this->process_id);
      //look for all provinces
      $provinces = Province::all();
      //cicle them
      foreach($provinces as $province)
      {
          //questa query mi dà una collection con tutti i movimenti per quel mese/anno/provincia
          $movements = Movement::where('process_id', '=', $process->id)->where('district', '=', $province['code'])->get();
          $movements = $movements->toArray();

          if(!empty($movements))
          {
              //passo il risultato alla funzione che fa il pdf
              //GENERATEPDFHELPER

              $test = new GeneratePdfHelper($movements);
              $test->create_pdf();
              
          }         
      }
      //Update the record in DB
        $process->update(['is_pdf_generated' => 1]);
    }
}
```

```
<?php
namespace app\Helpers; // Your helpers namespace 

use PDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


if(!class_exists('GeneratePdfHelper')){

    class GeneratePdfHelper
    {
        public $movements;

        public function __construct(array $movements){
            $this->movements = $movements;
        }

        public function create_pdf(){
        
        //contatore per vedere quanti record ci sono per i movimenti di quel processo per quella provincia
        $count = count($this->movements);
        //totale ritenute e ruolo
        $amount = 0; // ritenute
        $roles = array(); //ruoli

            foreach($this->movements as $key => $movement){
                $amount = $amount + $movement['amount'];
                if(!array_key_exists($movement['position'], $roles)){
                    $roles[$movement['position']] = 0;
                    $roles[$movement['position']] = $roles[$movement['position']] + 1;
                } else {
                    $roles[$movement['position']] = $roles[$movement['position']] + 1;
                }
            }

            $summary = array();
            $summary['amount'] = $amount;
            $summary['count'] = $count;
            $summary['roles'] = $roles;

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.index', ['movements' => $this->movements, 'summary' => $summary])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            $content = $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
            Storage::put("processes/{$this->movements[0]['process_id']}/{$this->movements[0]['district']}.pdf", $content);
     
          }        

        }
    }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it-IT">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Titolo</title>
<style>
    @page{size:29.7cm 21cm; margin:0px}
    body{margin:0px}
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="padding: 0;">
        <div id="wrapper" style="background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0; padding: 10px 0; width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
            <div cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <!-- Header -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_header" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #d4d4d4; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 25px;">
                            <h1 style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 35px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: left; color: #000; background-color: inherit;'><strong>{{$movements[0]['district']}}</strong></h1>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 25px;">
                            <div style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 25px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: right; color: #6b6b6b; background-color: inherit; font-style: italic;'>(Mese di confronto: {{$movements[0]['month_payment']}}/{{$movements[0]['year_payment']}})</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- End Header -->


                <!-- Middle -->
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_middle" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px;'>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 25px; width: 50%;  vertical-align: top;">
                            <div style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: left; color: #000; background-color: inherit;'>
                                <div style="padding: 8px 0;">
                                    <strong>Iscritti:</strong> {{$summary['count']}}
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding: 8px 0;">
                                    <strong>Nuove iscrizioni:</strong> ?
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #eaeaea; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; margin-top: 10px;'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 15px;">
                                        <strong>Ritenute nel mese:</strong> ?
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 15px;">
                                        <strong>Riattivazioni:</strong> ?
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 15px;">
                                        <strong>Cessazioni:</strong> ?
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; margin-top: 10px;'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 70%; padding-right: 5px;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #eaeaea; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; padding: 15px;'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>TOTALE (ritenute rimborsi):</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    {{$summary['amount']}}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>Quota al Nazionale:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    ?
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>NETTO per la Sede prov.:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    €355,62
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 30%; padding-left: 5px; vertical-align: top;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #eaeaea; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; padding: 15px;'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>ATA:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    16
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>DOCENTI:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    33
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>ITP:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0; text-align: right;">
                                                    0
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #eaeaea; color: #000; border-bottom: 0; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; padding: 15px; margin-top: 10px;'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>Precari:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    5
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px;">
                                                    <strong>Pensionandi:</strong>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 0 0 10px; text-align: right;">
                                                    0
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding: 25px; width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">
                            <div style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 120%; margin: 0; text-align: left; color: #000; background-color: inherit; font-style: italic; border: 1px solid; padding: 15px;'>
                                <p style="margin: 0 0 20px;">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                </p>
                                <p style="margin: 0 0 20px;">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- End Middle -->


                    <!-- Righe nominativi -->
                    <div style='font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: left; color: #000; background-color: inherit;'>
                    <strong>1 - RITENUTE NEL Mese</strong>
                    </div>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="template_middle" style='display: inline-table; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 11px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: left;'>
                                <tr style="background-color: #ffffff; font-style: italic;">
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;  width: 10px;">
                                        Partita
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        SS
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Eta'
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Nominativo
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Qualifica
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Sede di servizio
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Tel sede
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Fax sede
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
                                        Scadenze
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach ($movements as $movement)
                                            <tr style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    {{$movement['receipt_id']}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    M
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    54
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    {{$movement['name_lastname']}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    {{$movement['position']}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    ANIC83300cc Senigallia Marchetti
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    0717922289
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    07165487
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding: 10px;">
                                                    202106 scadenza contratto
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                            </table>
                    <!-- End Righe nominativi -->
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your job code? it seem's crazy it has to do it for 8 minutes?

Comment: @mrhn sure, hope it helps.

Comment: 1. dont ever use class_exists('GeneratePdfHelper') if you have to you have changed something in the settings. 2. how do you start the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your approach seems wrong or kinda misunderstood, in regards to what a job actually achieves. Jobs are short running jobs that executes code that prevents the `Http` server from responding slow and is a more scalable solution. This is not as black and white, but in general long running tasks is more suited for commands.

You are using 2000 `mb` of ram, that is a lot and as long as you keep on adding models it will be higher. Instead create multiple small jobs that does the same, each job will cleanup after itself and therefor never exceed the memory limit, while also being able to execute multiple `pdf's` simultaneously.

Create a job for a single `Movement`.

```
class GeneratePdfFile implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $province;

    public $process_id;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Province $province, $process_id)
    {
        $this->province = $province;
        $this->process_id = $process_id;
    }

    public function handle() {
      $movements = Movement::where('process_id', '=', $process->id)->where('district', '=', $this->province['code'])->get();
      $movements = $movements->toArray();

      if(!empty($movements))
      {
          //passo il risultato alla funzione che fa il pdf
          //GENERATEPDFHELPER

          $test = new GeneratePdfHelper($movements);
          $test->create_pdf();
      }    
    }
}
```

Then when creating the job instead loop your `Province` there.

```
foreach($provinces as $province)
{
    dispatch(new GeneratePdfFile($province, $process_id));
}
```

Comment: Having filled out everything your old job did, but i think you get the idea, a job that does that operation is to long for a long running job. If your system gets double as big you need to allocate 4gb of ram and it will keep rising.

Comment: thanks, now I understand better the queues. How would you notify when all these jobs are done? Before I was doing an operation after the foreach, but now not sure how to do.

Comment: Thats the tricky part queues is not good at that, before i have tied all pdfs to a single row in the db and then when the job is done, you can check if all these rows have pdf's and if so notify. But your data does not seem to have those relationships as of now.